# Android: modifying string resources under layout xml

Tags: android, string, layout, resources

I have a layout in which I put the TextView:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/loginLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login" />
```

I want to use **@string/login** resource as text, but i would like to add a colon after it without creating two values:

```
<string name="login">Login</string>
<string name="loginWithColon">Login:</string>
```

Have somebody any idea for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. You should use two resources.

But the second resource can extend the login so you can update one and reflect changes.

```
<string name="login">Login</string>
<string name="loginWithColon">@string/login:</string>
```

You can, in Java code, treat it like a `String` and do what you want like a normal string. But you cannot change it inside resource files. Example you could set the text in Java code and use the normal `+` operator.